# Laravel: Notifications table with custom column

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, customization

I am using Laravel's default `notifications` system. However, I need an extra column in the `notifications` table to check if the user already has the same unread-notification or not.

*For example: If user's profile is not complete then on every login he/she will be reminded until the profile is complete. But if the previously generated notification is still `unread` then the new `notification` will not be generated.*

Table: notifications

| default_fields | notify | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | profile_incomplete | ... |
| ... | password_change_overdue | ... |

Notifications class

```php
class NotifyToCompleteProfileNotification extends Notification
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->notify = 'profile_incomplete';
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'data' => '...',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Default Laravel notifications system already has `type` column carrying used notification class name.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is just an example.

Comment: Got it, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom notification channel to make this works. Let's assume you want to add a `group` field to notifications. First, add this field to table, then make file `GroupedDbChannel.php`:

```php
namespace App\Notifications;


use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class GroupedDbChannel
{
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        $data = $notification->toDatabase($notifiable);
        return $notifiable->routeNotificationFor('database')->create([
            'id' => $notification->id,
            'group' => $notification->group,
            'type' => get_class($notification),
            'data' => $data,
            'read_at' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Next, you need to define custom group and channel for notification:

```php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class TestNotification extends Notification {

    /*
     * Here you define additional value that will
     * be used in custom notification channel.
     */
    public string $group = 'incomplete-profile';
    

    public function via($notifiable) {
        return [GroupedDbChannel::class];
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable) {
        return [
            // notification data
        ];
    }

    /*
     * It's important to define toDatabase method due 
     * it's used in notification channel. Of course, 
     * you can change it in GroupedDbChannel.
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable): array
    {
        return $this->toArray($notifiable);
    }

}
```

And it's done. Use notifications as standard.

```php
$user->notify(new TestNotification());
```

Now, value `incomplete-profile` from `$group` field goes to `notifications` table to `group` column.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this